# Conflict between packages breqn and siunitx?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, breqn

I'd like to use `siunitx` package to write an equation like this:

[image]

However, when I try to use `\SI` in **math mode** I get a very strange result:

[image]

After some tries, I think I managed to find what is causing this behaviour and it apparently is the `breqn` package. Here's a MWE of the strange behaviour:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

Math:

\[\mathit{LostVariance} \approx \SI{28.2}{\percent} \]

\end{document}
```

I'm using LuaLaTex as engine. Does anybody know how can I fix this?

[EDIT1]

As requested in the comments, I added `listfiles` before `\documentclass` and recompiled. Maybe I should also notice that I'm using Overleaf. Here's the log:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2018.1.13)  22 MAR 2018 13:16
 system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\l@dumylang=\language1
\l@nohyphenation=\language2
\l@galician=\language3
\l@serbianc=\language4
\l@oriya=\language5
\l@nynorsk=\language6
\l@latvian=\language7
\l@ukenglish=\language8
\l@classiclatin=\language9
\l@kannada=\language10
\l@occitan=\language11
\l@arabic=\language12
\l@turkish=\language13
\l@irish=\language14
\l@basque=\language15
\l@ukrainian=\language16
\l@romanian=\language17
\l@bulgarian=\language18
\l@armenian=\language19
\l@welsh=\language20
\l@latin=\language21
\l@coptic=\language22
\l@spanish=\language23
\l@russian=\language24
\l@german-x-2014-05-21=\language25
\l@croatian=\language26
\l@czech=\language27
\l@telugu=\language28
\l@icelandic=\language29
\l@swedish=\language30
\l@dutch=\language31
\l@portuguese=\language32
\l@gujarati=\language33
\l@malayalam=\language34
\l@turkmen=\language35
\l@sanskrit=\language36
\l@liturgicallatin=\language37
\l@serbian=\language38
\l@uppersorbian=\language39
\l@romansh=\language40
\l@greek=\language41
\l@indonesian=\language42
\l@ngerman=\language43
\l@assamese=\language44
\l@churchslavonic=\language45
\l@italian=\language46
\l@ibycus=\language47
\l@french=\language48
\l@monogreek=\language49
\l@mongolian=\language50
\l@farsi=\language51
\l@pinyin=\language52
\l@slovenian=\language53
\l@hungarian=\language54
\l@esperanto=\language55
\l@kurmanji=\language56
\l@interlingua=\language57
\l@danish=\language58
\l@usenglishmax=\language59
\l@bengali=\language60
\l@mongolianlmc=\language61
\l@bokmal=\language62
\l@polish=\language63
\l@estonian=\language64
\l@marathi=\language65
\l@ngerman-x-2014-05-21=\language66
\l@afrikaans=\language67
\l@thai=\language68
\l@lithuanian=\language69
\l@tamil=\language70
\l@finnish=\language71
\l@ethiopic=\language72
\l@slovak=\language73
\l@ancientgreek=\language74
\l@piedmontese=\language75
\l@catalan=\language76
\l@german=\language77
\l@friulan=\language78
\l@hindi=\language79
\l@swissgerman=\language80
\l@panjabi=\language81
\l@georgian=\language82
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2016/04/23 3.9r Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def))
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf
Language: italian 2015/03/26 v1.3n Italian support from the babel system
\it@lettering=\count88
\it@doublequoteactive=\count89
\it@ISOcompliance=\count90

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-it.tex
UTF-8 Italian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-it.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/quote/hyph-quote-
it.tex)))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count91
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15


Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (code)
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2016/02/12 v6412 L3 Bootstrap code
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
L3 Module: l3names 2016/03/11 v6433 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2015/11/22 v6315 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2016/03/24 v6441 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2015/08/05 v5777 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2016/03/24 v6441 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count92
\l_tmpa_int=\count93
\l_tmpb_int=\count94
\g_tmpa_int=\count95
\g_tmpb_int=\count96
L3 Module: l3quark 2015/08/17 v5855 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2015/11/01 v6216 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count97
L3 Module: l3clist 2015/09/02 v5901 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2016/04/03 v6470 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2016/01/05 v6366 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2016/03/26 v6464 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2016/03/25 v6458 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count98
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count99
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count100
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count101
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count102
L3 Module: l3skip 2016/01/05 v6366 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen104
\c_max_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen106
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen108
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen109
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2015/11/17 v6284 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count103
\l_keys_choice_int=\count104
L3 Module: l3fp 2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count112
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count113
L3 Module: l3box 2015/08/09 v5822 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
L3 Module: l3coffins 2016/05/17 v6508 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen115
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen116
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen119
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3sys 2015/09/25 v6087 L3 Experimental system/runtime functions
L3 Module: l3candidates 2016/05/13 v6484 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen127
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen134
L3 Module: l3luatex 2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count114
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count115
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count116
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count117
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count118
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count119
)
Package: siunitx 2016/03/01 v2.6q A comprehensive (SI) units package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen135
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen136
\extrarowheight=\dimen137
\NC@list=\toks17
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2016/05/18 v6512 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__siunitx_tmp_box=\box42
\l__siunitx_tmp_dim=\dimen138
\l__siunitx_tmp_int=\count120
\l__siunitx_number_mantissa_length_int=\count121
\l__siunitx_number_uncert_length_int=\count122
\l__siunitx_round_int=\count123
\l__siunitx_process_decimal_int=\count124
\l__siunitx_process_uncertainty_int=\count125
\l__siunitx_process_fixed_int=\count126
\l__siunitx_process_integer_min_int=\count127
\l__siunitx_process_precision_int=\count128
\l__siunitx_group_min_int=\count129
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box43
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box44
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_dim=\dimen139
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_dim=\dimen140
\l__siunitx_unit_int=\count130
\l__siunitx_unit_denominator_int=\count131
\l__siunitx_unit_numerator_int=\count132
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_int=\count133
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_base_int=\count134
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_gram_int=\count135
\l__siunitx_number_product_int=\count136
\c__siunitx_one_fill_skip=\skip51
\l__siunitx_table_unit_align_skip=\skip52
\l__siunitx_table_exponent_dim=\dimen141
\l__siunitx_table_integer_dim=\dimen142
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_dim=\dimen143
\l__siunitx_table_marker_dim=\dimen144
\l__siunitx_table_result_dim=\dimen145
\l__siunitx_table_uncert_dim=\dimen146
\l__siunitx_table_fill_pre_dim=\dimen147
\l__siunitx_table_fill_post_dim=\dimen148
\l__siunitx_table_fill_mid_dim=\dimen149
\l__siunitx_table_pre_box=\box45
\l__siunitx_table_post_box=\box46
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_box=\box47
\l__siunitx_table_result_box=\box48
\l__siunitx_table_number_align_skip=\skip53
\l__siunitx_table_text_align_skip=\skip54
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareBinaryPrefix with sig. 'mmm' on line 7218.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPostPower with sig. 'mm' on line 7221.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPrefix with sig. 'mmm' on line 7224.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPrePower with sig. 'mm' on line 7227.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIQualifier with sig. 'mm' on line 7230.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIUnit with sig. 'O{}mm' on line 7233.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIUnitWithOptions with sig. 'mmm' on line 7236.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \ang with sig. 'o>{\SplitArgument {2}{;}}m' on line 7251.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \num with sig. 'om' on line 7260.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numlist with sig. 'o>{\SplitList {;}}m' on line 7269.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numrange with sig. 'omm' on line 7278.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIlist with sig. 'o>{\SplitList {;}}mm' on line 7290.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIrange with sig. 'ommm' on line 7302.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SI with sig. 'omom' on line 7314.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \sisetup with sig. 'm' on line 7317.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \tablenum with sig. 'om' on line 7332.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \si with sig. 'om' on line 7344.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__siunitx_bookmark_num:w with sig. 'om' on line 7391.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__siunitx_bookmark_numrange:w with sig. 'omm' on line
. 7393.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__siunitx_bookmark_SI:w with sig. 'omom' on line 7395.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__siunitx_bookmark_SIlist:w with sig. 'omm' on line 7397.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__siunitx_bookmark_SIrange:w with sig. 'ommm' on line
. 7399.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__siunitx_bookmark_si:w with sig. 'om' on line 7400.
.................................................
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
Package: translator 2010/06/12 ver 1.10

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-
mappings.tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/breqn.sty
Package: breqn 2015/08/11 v0.98d Breaking equations

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/flexisym.sty
Package: flexisym 2015/08/11 v0.98d Make math characters macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textprime on input line 299.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \not on input line 357.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/cmbase.sym
File: cmbase.sym 2007/12/19 v0.92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \hbar on input line 324.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \surd on input line 326.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \angle on input line 334.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \neq on input line 335.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mapsto on input line 336.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cong on input line 337.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \notin on input line 340.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rightleftharpoons on input line 341.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \doteq on input line 342.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \hookrightarrow on input line 343.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \hookleftarrow on input line 344.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bowtie on input line 345.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \models on input line 346.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longrightarrow on input line 347.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longrightarrow on input line 348.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longleftarrow on input line 349.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longleftarrow on input line 350.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longmapsto on input line 351.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longleftrightarrow on input line 352.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longleftrightarrow on input line 353.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 357.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \vdots on input line 360.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ddots on input line 365.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty
Package: mathstyle 2015/08/11 v0.98d Tracking mathstyle implicitly
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count137
\calc@Bcount=\count138
\calc@Adimen=\dimen150
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen151
\calc@Askip=\skip55
\calc@Bskip=\skip56
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count139
\calc@Cskip=\skip57
)
\inf@bad=\count140
\maxint=\count141
\listwidth=\dimen152
\eqnumsep=\dimen153
\eqmargin=\dimen154
\eqlinespacing=\skip58
\eqlineskip=\skip59
\eqlineskiplimit=\dimen155
\eqbinoffset=\muskip16
\eqdelimoffset=\muskip17
\eqindentstep=\dimen156
\eqstyle=\toks19
\eqbreakdepth=\count142
\eqinterlinepenalty=\count143
\intereqpenalty=\count144
\intereqskip=\skip60
\prerelpenalty=\count145
\prebinoppenalty=\count146
\Dmedmuskip=\muskip18
\Dthickmuskip=\muskip19
\eqleftskip=\skip61
\eqrightskip=\skip62
\eq@vspan=\skip63
\eq@binoffset=\muskip20
\EQ@box=\box49
\EQ@copy=\box50
\EQ@numbox=\box51
\eq@wdNum=\dimen157
\GRP@numbox=\box52
\grp@wdNum=\dimen158
\eq@lines=\count147
\eq@curline=\count148
\eq@badness=\count149
\EQ@vims=\count150
\eq@dp=\dimen159
\eq@wdL=\dimen160
\eq@wdT=\dimen161
\eq@wdMin=\dimen162
\grp@wdL=\dimen163
\grp@wdR=\dimen164
\grp@wdT=\dimen165
\eq@wdRmax=\dimen166
\eq@firstht=\dimen167
\eq@wdCond=\dimen168
\eq@indentstep=\dimen169
\eq@linewidth=\dimen170
\grp@linewidth=\dimen171
\eq@hshift=\dimen172
\eq@given@sidespace=\dimen173
\mathindent=\dimen174
\eq@final@linecount=\count151
\eq@wdR=\dimen175
\EQ@continue=\toks20
\lr@level=\count152
\GRP@queue=\toks21
\c@parentequation=\count153
\GRP@box=\box53
\GRP@wholebox=\box54
\darraycolsep=\skip64
\cur@row=\count154
\cur@col=\count155
\conditionsep=\skip65
) (./main.aux)
\openout1 = main.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \it@ocap on input line 10.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \it@ccap on input line 10.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-bas
ic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2016/03/01 v2.6q siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
\c__siunitx_mathsf_int=\count156
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 10.
\c__siunitx_mathtt_int=\count157

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
 italian.ldf    2015/03/26 v1.3n Italian support from the babel system
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
 siunitx.sty    2016/03/01 v2.6q A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
translator-language-mappings.tex
   breqn.sty    2015/08/11 v0.98d Breaking equations
flexisym.sty    2015/08/11 v0.98d Make math characters macros
  cmbase.sym    2007/12/19 v0.92
mathstyle.sty    2015/08/11 v0.98d Tracking mathstyle implicitly
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2016/03/01 v2.6q siunitx: Abbreviated units
 ***********

)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 11576 strings out of 495118
 125171,266212 words of node,token memory allocated
 524 words of node memory still in use:
   4 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 17 glue, 57 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:17,3:37,4:3,5:14,6:42,7:49,8:26,9:25
 14950 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 45 fonts using 1871735 bytes
 36i,6n,43p,792b,769s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/share/texlive/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.p
fb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb></us
r/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 71560 bytes).

PDF statistics: 45 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 32 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I do not get that output from your example. Can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, compile again, and then add the `.log` file to your question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Done!

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it has probably been fixed I think. On Overleaf I have version 2.6q and 0.98d of `siunitx` and `breqn` respectively, and there the problem appears. On my own computer, with versions 2.7k and 0.98e, the problem does not appear.